# Group of users cannot see items in the document library

Tags: permissions, inheritance

It appears, that a couple of users are unable to see items being published on particular document library. For example, users in Mumbai are able to see those files, but users in N.Y. are unable to see them in that particular document library.

I tried to advise them to check permissions for the user (and checked them by myself) and it seems like the user(s) have all required permissions to see library content.

Also, I get Full Control permissions to the whole site, and I was unable to see items in that library too.

What I need to know is how I could advise users with this issue. At this point of the process I just don't know what to do. I think it has something to do with permissions inheritance, but maybe you guys know what do do in this kind of situation?

Thank you all and appreciate any help.

**EDIT:** Maybe I could advise them to Stop Inheriting PErmission on this particular library and grant those permissions again for the same documents library?

Comment: Are they unable to see all of the documents in that library, or can they see only some documents? Are your Mumbai users in a different permissions group from your NY users?

Comment: There is a document library named "Processes" which stores individual WORD items. Also, they are unable to see all items (where are about 1000 of them). I can't really tell if they are in the different permission groups by now (as I'm not at work at the moment). But it probably should be if they're saying that NY users cannot see items, and Mumbai are able to do so. Thank you.

Comment: Is content approval required (under versioning settings?)

Comment: @DeimantasBrandišauskas What version of SharePoint is this for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. **Manage Files With No Checked In Version:** Go to Library Settings and click the "Manage files which have no checked in version" link. If users have uploaded files but not checked them in, the users who uploaded the documents will be the only ones who can see them. Fortunately, the site owner can take ownership of checked out files, then check them in.
2. **Version Access:** Go to Library Settings and click the "Versioning Settings" link. If "Content Approval" is turned on, then only people with access to Approve items will be able to see unapproved items. Similarly, if "Create major and minor (draft) versions" is checked, double-check what the "Draft Item Security" is set to-- you probably want it to be "Any user who can read items"
3. **Permissions:** Finally, go to Permissions for this document library and confirm that there are no documents or folders with unique permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Also check the current view to make sure your filter is set to:  "Show all items in this view"