# User Cannot See Documents in Library

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-library

I have given a licensed user read permissions to a site collection, and she is able to get to a sub-site and document library, but cannot see any of the documents in there. I checked the permissions for the document library, but it is inheriting from the parent site, which should be correct.

Ideas on what is causing this?

Comment: Can only you see the documents? If so, are the documents checked out to you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group of users cannot see items in the document library](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158400/group-of-users-cannot-see-items-in-the-document-library)

Answer (score 0):

there are many possible cause for this

1. Check the view of the user, May be view having some filters in it?
2. create a new for her
3. check if the Documents have item level permission
4. try different browser
5. check if document is checked in, and if there is any workflow attach to it then it is completed.
6. if their is publishing then make sure Document is published
7. may be give her edit permission for testing purpose

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint you can also have permissions at a document level, this might be one cause.

If not maybe your files were never archived and so cannot be seen by any other user than the one who uploaded them.

There is one last thing we use in our company, it's unique permissions but on folder level only, the catch being that after creating all the folders and applying the permissions, we only use views that displays the files without folders.